# what system calls are used to copy files in Linux

Tags: linux, io, system-calls

I am modifying ext4 filesystem to add a simple encryption to files contents.
I started by changing read and write system calls to change the contents right before write and after read system calls.

now copying files in terminal is working just as I expected but when I try to copy a file using a GUI based file manager (pcmanfm in this case) it is corrupting the contents.

my question is: what system calls are used for reading/writing files besides normal .read and .write?

Comment: That can be implementation dependent. Every file manager is free to choose whether is uses `read/write`, `fread/fwrite`, `buffered/unbuffered`, calling 3rd party-apps (like `dd` or `rsync`) or the like. Look at the `pcmanfm` source code.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin thank you. so let me ask something else, if I want to encrypt data written to disk, I have to modify various filesystem related calls? or is there any point that these are related to filesystem drivers functions?

Comment: It is a spiderweb of varying implementations. From a filesystem standpoint [**dm-crypt/Encrypting an entire system**](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dm-crypt/Encrypting_an_entire_system) is an excellent reference. It cannot be done by trying to catch system calls, you must pick an implementation for your type filesystem.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin here is the thing I dont understand: aren't all these system calls using filesystem driver to finally write to disk? do they all use their own methode even in a single filesystem? for example about ext4, aren't all read/write command use functions provides by ext4 file operations structure in file.c inside ext4 driver?

Comment: I will be the firs to admit you have just asked a question beyond my firm understanding. You would think that every filesystem would have some unique `read/write` that all functions ultimately filter down to calling before the cylinders/tracks/sectors are written, but I don't know for sure if it is 100% under a filesystem standard or under a looser API.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin thank you. so far, this conversation has been very helpful for me. and the reference that you mentioned is a good one. I may end up reading source codes of those implementations to learn more.

Answer (score 1):

mmap, sendfile, etc

If you want crypto in ext4, you should probably look at the google's recent patch to Linux just for that,

http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=EXT4-Encryption-Support